# Rebuild objects in multiple libraries based on one set of dependency files

Tags: makefile

I'm compiling a static library (archive) with one set of source files for multiple platforms/architectures. There's a unique set of `.o` object files put into each library for each unique platform. However, the `.d` dependency files aren't (don't need to be) unique for each platform. Since the archives contain the objects, I would prefer to remove the duplicate sets of objects after compiling, because they take a lot of space.

What rule/command do I create in a makefile with gnu make to recompile/replace some objects in an archive if they're older than the prerequisites from a `.d` dependency rule with a certain matching name?

My makefile attempt.

```
OBJ := fileA.o fileB.o
lib/libraryALin64.a: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(OBJ:%.o=src/%.cpp) -c -o $(OBJ:%=src/obj/Lin64/%) -MMD $(OBJ:%.o=src/dep/%.d)
    $(AR) rs $@ $(OBJ:%=src/obj/Lin64/%)

-include $(OBJ:%.o=src/dep/%.d) # the objects' dependency rules should exist now?
```

The directory structure.

```
lib/
    libraryALin64.a
    libraryAWin32.lib
src/
    fileA.cpp
    fileA.h
    dep/
        fileA.d
    obj/ # I would like to not need the objects in here. 
        Lin64/
            fileA.o
        Win32/
            fileA.o
Makefile
```

In other words, when `make` is executed, for the example target `lib/libraryALin64.a` compare `lib/libraryALin64.a(fileA.o)` to the prerequisite files found from `src/dep/fileA.d` and do that for all objects in the library, recompile and replace the objects as necessary. Then repeat for each library.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question: you manage a dependency `fileA.o: src/fileA.cpp` without distinguishing whether it is `Lin64/fileA.o` or `Win32/fileA.o`. This is a result from directly placing the output into the `lib` archives, but I doubt that this mechanism was created with different platforms in mind.

As the object files from the same source for different platforms obviously are meant to exist in parallel, I think it is an error to allow the dependency rule as such because it implies a semantic which is simply not there in `make`: dependencies are meant to be between real files (exception: `VPATH`, see below) and are formulated from the destination file's viewpoint. They are not intended to express an ostensible, theoretical project structure. `libraryALin64.lib` is not dependent on a file `fileA.o` but instead on the specific `obj/Lin64/fileA.o`.

This is also the reason why `VPATH` is used *to locate source, not destination files*: Usually, the execution of recipe commands is thought to happen from inside the destination directory which is why rule targets are rarely seen to carry path information with them (`fileA.o:` instead of `obj/Lin64/fileA.o:`) and for the sake of simplicity one should also store the `.d` files there, eliminating the confusion of which file would be the target.

So my recommendation for the proper solution of your question would be: rewrite the makefile to a standard build method by redirecting compilation to the object directory and don't try to create some hybrid of makefile and project description.